# How to render two different applications for mobile applications for mobile and web under the same domain?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, nginx

I am developing a product which is built on React Native for iOS/android/mobile and React.js for Web, I am using firebase for backend. I would like to know if there is any way to deploy these two apps under the same domain where corresponding app will be rendered based on platform.

Comment: React Native apps are installed from the app/play store, and not hosted on a web domain.

Comment: Yes but I am also rendering the native version on mobile web.